# $_GET['id'] doesn't fetch id

Tags: php

```
            <?php
            //categoryview.php
            include 'connection.php';
            include 'header.php';
             mysql_select_db('forum');
            //first select the category based on $_GET['cat_id'
            $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
            $sql = "SELECT
                        forum_id,
                        forum_name,
                        forum_description
                    FROM
                        forums
                    WHERE
                        forum_id = '".$id."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' . mysql_error();
            }
            else
            {
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'This category does not exist.';
                    mysql_error();
                }   
                else
                {
                    //display category data
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<h2>Topics in ′' . $row['forum_name'] . '′ category</h2>';
                    }

            //do a query for the topics
            $sql = "SELECT  
                        thread_id,
                        thread_subject,
                        thread_date,
                        thread_category
                    FROM
                        threads
                    WHERE
                        threads.thread_category = '".$id."'";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
                echo mysql_error();
            }
            else
            {
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'There are no topics in this category yet.';
                }
                else
                {
                    //prepare the table
                    echo '<table border="1">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Created at</th>
                          </tr>'; 

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {               
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                                echo '<h3><a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['thread_id'] . '">' . $row['thread_subject'] . '</a><h3>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                                echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['thread_date']));
                            echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    ?>
```

hey guys im having a problem with my `$_GET['id']`. When I try loading this page it is supposed to show the threads that have been created in the forum i clicked on. The forum_id in the database contains integer values. e.g. forum named gardening has integer 1.
The problem im facing is that when i click on the forum from the index page this page loads up and the url bar shows `http://localhost/forum/categoryview.php?id` and when i add `php?id=1` at the end all the thread in the gardening forum show up

index.php

```
            <?php
            include 'connection.php';
            include 'header.php';
             mysql_select_db('forum');
            $sql = "SELECT
                        forum_id,
                        forum_name,
                        forum_description
                    FROM
                        forums";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                echo 'The categories could not be displayed, please try again later.';
                echo mysql_error();
            }
            else
            {
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'No categories defined yet.';
                    echo mysql_error();
                }   
                else
                {
                    //prepare the table
                    echo '<table border="1">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Last topic</th>
                          </tr>'; 

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {               
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                                echo '<h3><a href="categoryview.php?id">' . $row['forum_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $row['forum_description'];
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                                        echo '<a href="topic.php?id=">Topic subject</a> at 10-10';
                            echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }

                }
            }

            ?>
```

thats the index page thats linked to the categoryview. When you click on forum_name it should take you to categoryview which shows all the threads in that forum

Comment: if I understand.. the code you show here has nothing to do with the problem. Whatever link you clicked on to reach this simply lacks the number after ?id=   .. but you probably should code for the likely absence 
`if (!is_numeric($_GET['id']){ $id=1;} else {$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);}`

Comment: if you use `var_dump()` within the mysql_fetch loop on the `$row['thread_id']` value, what do you get?

Comment: `</a><h3>` that needs to read as `</a></h3>` might not fix your code but it should be closed properly

Comment: Where is code who makes this ` http://localhost/forum/categoryview.php?id` ?

Comment: hey guys ive added the index code that links to the categoryview